# How to make Query between two tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I want to ask for how to make query in 2 tables to get the summary of value from table payments where type_id = id from types table and this is tables structure

[image: types table]

[image: payments table]

this is the charts code

```
$chartـin_contract = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
        ->title('My nice chart')
        ->labels($value_type->type)
        ->values([5,10])
        ->dimensions(0,500);
```

in labels i get the values from database but did't work with me

and this is the direct query

```
$value_type = DB::select('select type, value from payments,types where payments.`type_id` = types.id');
```

I want view the data that came from database in chart I am using laravel chart package

Comment: please share your code what you tried so far.. thisis very less information to understand

Comment: I added it please see it

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to establish the **Relationship** in tables.

> NOTE: I am assuming that your task may have multiple payments

In your **tasks** model its **one to many** relation.

### Task.php (Model add the following)

```
public function payments(){
   return $this->hasMany(Payments::class);
}
```

And in your **payments** model its **many to one** relation.

### Payments.php (Assuming)

```
public function task(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Think now you want to get all the **payments** for a task. Let me show the eg: in command line

```
php artisan tinker

$task = App\Task::where('id',1)->get(); //Think that you have first task

$task->payments; //You can call the relation ship established condition function
```

Think you are browising for payment and want a task then

php artisan tinker

$payment = App\Payment::where('id',1)->get();//find the payment with id 1, just for the sake of example

$payment->task; //This will be the task() function that you have written int the model

Answer (score 0):

Please review Eloquent Relationships in the Laravel docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

The relationship between the two tables is defined (as in a one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship) and then you will be able to query those relationships.